# Screen Glitching on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, graphics

everyone.
Just got a brand new Asus Zenbook UX391. It came with Windows 10 Pro preinstalled. I partitioned the SSD to accommodate for dual booting with Ubuntu. I'm a rookie when it comes to stuff like this, but I followed the Ubuntu tutorial verbatim. However, there are these strange screen glitches as shown here:

https://youtu.be/cz69NWLBMLY?t=19s

I listed the specs of the laptop in the video's description, but I'll list them here, too.

Specs are
16GB of RAM
Core i7-8550U
Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)

Gnome version: 3.28.1
64-bit OS

As a side note, I allocated 150GB for Ubuntu, but Ubuntu itself says that the disk size is 157GB. I'm not sure if that's a problem.

Comment: Oh, and Ubuntu is perfectly functional throughout all of this. It's just purely this screen glitch that's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This question's been asked before and recently been answered with the solution, https://askubuntu.com/a/1058132/854773.

To sum up the solution:
1. Edit your grub file: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Place in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` string: `intel_idle.max_cstate=4`
3. Update the grub: `update-grub`
4. Reboot your machine for the changes to take effect.

If you're wondering what the grub line should roughly look like after you edit it, here's an example of mine: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=4"`
This is with no other alteration.

I'm not in the know of what's exactly happening, but it seems that Ubuntu doesn't yet know how to distribute power properly to the screen when trying to energy save on a 4K laptop monitor. This problem is seen in both C-State 5 and 6, rc5 and rc6 respectively, which is why we limit it to C-State 4 via the `intel_idle.max_cstate=4`.

Resources:
- https://gist.github.com/wmealing/2dd2b543c4d3cff6cab7 General users guide to C-States
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/power-management-states-p-states-c-states-and-package-c-states Intel's intro to  P-States and C-States