# Asus Zenbook UX391UA - Screen flickers

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, video, asus

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 I had problem with screen fliperring.

Comment: What's your question? If the fix fixes the issue, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Hello  Pawel, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected? Maybe you can include a video-link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with the addition of the kernel command-line parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=4` into `/etc/default/grub`:

```
grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_idle.max_cstate=4"

update-grub2
reboot
```

Comment: I have same issue, I'm using AMD Ryzen 5 (Asus and Ubuntu 22.04). What string to be added instead of intel_idle.max_cstate?