# Ubuntu 18.04 Screen flickering on a 4K laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics, 4k-monitor

I recently bought Lenovo Ideapad 720s (4K) and Dual Booted Ubuntu 18.04. However the screen is Flickering. I faced this even while installing but thought it would not happen once Ubuntu was set-up. I have tried the approach mentioned in [Asus Zenbook UX391UA - Screen flickers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058126/asus-zenbook-ux391ua-screen-flickers/1058132#1058132) but still no success. I am attaching a video for the same :
https://youtu.be/Fz7JkVIMPlk

Specs:
8GB of RAM
Core i7-8550U
Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
GNOME 3.28.2

The only workaround that I have found is to unplug power and then plug back in.(Works 98%). This issue has made my life miserable as it resurfaces as soon as I even lock sceen (and the screen turns off).

Please HELP!

Comment: You said 'dual boot', did you face the same thing with your other operating system? Because we had the same PC with the same problem in the company where I work and when we gave it back to the provider, it turned out to be a hardware problem.

Comment: No.. I haven't faced this issue with the other operating system. [Windows 10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108132) with the intel drivers and looking at their responses, I guess chances of it getting fixed anytime soon are bleak! Someone came up with a quick "fix" though. Add `i915.fastboot=1` to the kernel parameters. No flickering when booting and thereafter.

However, any time your screen turns black (screen lock or sleep) and starts again, flickering would return.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Lenovo++IdeaPad+720s+14IKB+Teardown/101860

I bought a lenovo tablet and had screen flickering too. My problem was solved by reseating the plastic circuit board ribbon cable into the proper ZIF connector. The zifs are easy to break and may have a flip method for the contact. Also the flip clicks into plastic and if that wears down the connection isnt good.

Perhaps a bit of doublesided tape or blue tack can help hold the ribbon down so that the tiny circuits do overlap or lose contact otherwise.

Comment: Oh man! but I am not facing this issue on a different OS!